# Possible error in DeviceOpen["Serial", ...]

Tags: python, input-devices

I'm using Mathematica to interface with a Feather M4 Express running Circuitpython.  Presently, the M4 is sending "hello" to the serial console in 1 second intervals.  It also has an on-board LED that I set to RED if there is no serial connection and BLUE if there is a serial connection.

**What works**

On the *Raspberry Pi* version 12.1 I can use:

```
d = DeviceOpen["Serial","/dev/ttyACM0"]
FromCharacterCode@DeviceReadBuffer[d]
```

And the output is whatever amount of the "hello hello ..." string that is in the buffer.  The M4 LED also turns blue.

**What doesn't work**

On Windows running Mathematica version 12.3 (also tried with version 12.0) the above command (with "COM3" instead of "/dev/ttyACM0") I get an indication *from Mathematica* that the device is connected; however the M4 LED stays RED.  Further, `DeviceReadBuffer` returns an empty string.

**Workaround**

If I instead use Python from within Mathematica, I can get the desired functionality.

```
ExternalEvaluate["Python", "import serial; s = serial.Serial('COM3');  out = s.read(10); s.close(); print(out)"]
```

I get the expected output along with a cycling of the M4 LED from red to blue back to red when the device is closed.

Lastly, it is interesting to note that while the M4 does not appear to register that a connection has been established when `DeviceOpen` is called, the COM3 port is blocked and if I try to run the python code in the same session following a `DeviceOpen`, an exception is raised.

If someone can confirm or agrees this is not working as intended, they can get some edit points and add the bug-tag.  Perhaps someone also knows a workaround that does not involve use of the external evaluator.

Comment: Did you try to explicitly set all the settings for the connection, such a baud rate, stop bits, etc? Unfortunately, I don't have the same microcontroller lying around, but I could successfully communicate with an Arduino I had lying around, using Mathematica 12.2 on Windows 10. So the serial communication stuff can in principle work.

Comment: @LukasLang Yes, I did set some of the parameters (just baudrate and stopbits) even though I did not have to on the RPi.  I am able to get DeviceOpen working fine with an Arduino, so can narrow the problem down to either the hardware (M4 Express) or software (Circuitpython).